# Python Pandas Excel Display

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I used the Python Pandas library as a wrap-around instead of using SQL.  Everything worked perfectly, except when I open the output excel file, the cells appear blank, but when I click on the cell, I can see the value in the cell above.  Additionally, Python and Stata recognize the value in the cell, even though the eye cannot see it.  Furthermore, if I do "text to columns", then the values in the cell become visible to the eye.

Clearly it's a pain to go through every column and click "text to columns", and I'm wondering the following:

(1) Why is the value not visible to the eye when it exists in the cell?

(2) What's the easiest way to make all the values visible to the eye aside from the cumbersome "text to columns" for all columns approach?

(3) I did a large number of tests to make sure the non-visible values in the cells in fact worked in analysis.  Is my assumption that the non-visible values in the cells will always be accurate, true?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: That doesn't sound like normal behaviour for the Pandas Excel writers. Can you post an example.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your python code is inserting a carriage return either before or after the value.

I've replicated this behavior in Excel 2016 and can confirm that the cell appears blank, but does contain a value.

Furthermore, I've verified that using the text to columns will parse the carriage return out.